# How to properly use variable substitutions in windows cmd?

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line-arguments

I'm using Ghost Script to operate PDF. I'm using numered variables as arguments. My input file name is "x.pdf". I want the output file to be "x-processed.pdf". Curently I have the above mentrioned code:

```
gswin64c.exe -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dPDFA=2 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dSimulateOverprint=true -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=150 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=150 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=150 -sOutputFile=%1%-processed.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %1
```

So the output file name is currently `inputfilename.pdf-processed.pdf`.
I want to remove that extension. But I can't figure out how.

I've tried to use variable substitutions form here: http://cplusplus.bordoon.com/cmd_exe_variables.html
That is to say, I've changed `-sOutputFile=%1-processed.pdf` to `-sOutputFile=%~pn1-processed.pdf`

That did not work.

So I've tried to look how to use these substitutions at first place. I've tried to copy selected file name to the clipboard by adding this command via regedit:
`cmd.exe echo "%~n1"|clip`
That does not work.
But if I put simply:
`cmd.exe /c echo "%1"|clip`
That works properly and copy file path with extention to the clipboard.

I'm really stuck as I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me.

No error messages. No messages at all. Nothing happens.

Comment: `-sOutputFile=%1%-processed.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %1` translates to `-sOutputFile=%11`, because the variable `%-processed.pdf -c .setpdfwrite -f %` is empty. (in other words, you have one `%` too much)

Comment: In fact it works both with %1% and %1. But I does not work with %~pn1 and that's the problem. I want to get rid of the file extention while renaming it.

Comment: "In fact it works both with %1% and %1" - it does not. Try `echo <your whole line>`  with both `sOutputFile=%1%-processed.pdf` and with `sOutputFile=%1-processed.pdf` and compare the outputs.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know how exactly the line should look like with echo. Would you mind to precise it, please?

I assume that it should not work. But technically it will create a new pdf in both cases with %1% and %1. It is weird, but I've tested and both do the same.

The question is more why %~dn1 is not working?

Comment: You are using the wrong terms. Open a command prompt window and run `set /?`. The output help explains how to use substitutions with environment variables. What you want to use is referencing first argument of batch file with a modifier. The help output on running in cmd window `call /?` explains how to do this. `%~pn1` means path and name of first argument without drive and without file extension. I suggest to use `-sOutputFile="%~dpn1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"` which definitely works even on calling the batch file with awful file name `"Test & Example_#1!.pdf"`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is synthetically correct I think it should have worked.

For some reason it did not. I don't know what could possibly be wrong by now. I'll removed -dNOPAUSE from the code. But each time I change %1 to anything else cmd window is just closing immediately. I cannot even get the error message. I've tried to put "pause" inside however it keeps closing with no results. 

There is certainly something I don't understand about the whole concept. It cannot be that complicated.

Comment: UPD: This is really weird. And I'm completely lost now.
If I use: ```-sOutputFile="%1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"``` it creates a blank 1-page PDF. 
If I use: ```'''-sOutputFile="%1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%1"``` it works properly creating a new PDF using the input.
If I put "~" in the -sOutputFile after"%" like this:
```-sOutputFile="%~1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"```
or
```-sOutputFile="%~dpn1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"``` as you suggested 

It would not generate any PDF and cmd windows would immediately close even if I put "pause" in.

Comment: do yourself a favor: for troubleshooting **don't** start it with a double click. Open a `cmd` window and run it manually from there - that way the window keeps open so you can read any error messages.

Comment: An error message states "Unabe to open the initial device, quitting". It appears every time I use %~ operator instead of % in -sOutputFile

Comment: Do you have saved the batch file as ANSI encoded text file and not as Unicode encoded text file? I copied your command line yesterday into an ANSI encoded batch file with the modification at end posted by me. I opened a cmd window and executed `"C:\Temp\test.bat" "C:\Temp\Test & Example_#1!.pdf"` and it worked with the warning posted by me and of course with source PDF file with that strange name really existing in `C:\Temp`. Well, I used full path to executable in batch file because Ghostscript `bin` directory is not in my `PATH`.

Comment: I've tried this: 
```@ECHO OFF
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dPDFA=2 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dSimulateOverprint=true -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=150 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=150 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=150 -sOutputFile="%~dpn1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"
PAUSE```
Actually it works.

Comment: But it works only while using a batch file. While trying to put this line to execute from windows context menu via registry it does not work. And it is intended to be used. I want that thing work this way "Right Click on .pdf -> Process". What is different while putting this command as Value Data in registry?

Comment: UPD: Thank you very much for your help. In fact the only way to do this is through setting path to .bat file.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is only few variables available when wring a shell command from context menu.
More info is in https://superuser.com/a/473602.

So the only way is to create a batch file with the above mentioned code:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.27\bin\gswin32c.exe" -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -dPDFA=2 -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dSimulateOverprint=true -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dEmbedAllFonts=true -dSubsetFonts=true -dAutoRotatePages=/None -dColorImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dColorImageResolution=150 -dGrayImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dGrayImageResolution=150 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Bicubic -dMonoImageResolution=150 -sOutputFile="%~dpn1-processed.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite -f "%~1"
```

And add the following command `REG_SZ` line instead of putting the command directly:

```
"Path_to_bat_file/file_name.bat" "%1"
```

And it should work.